How do I use "http" backend provider together with environment variables ? I set the required env variables on my computer, but it is not working
I wanted to set up Terraform "http" backend (https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/http) and one of the options (which is recommended) is to use environment variables as shown below:

I have set up those environment variables on my local machine (using export command) to point to my GitLab repository state storage and in the terraform{} block I leave the backend "http" {} block empty as shown:

But once I run the command terraform init , it still asks me to enter the data manually even though I have environment variables set up:

Why is that so ? Has anyone encountered similar situation and has an answer why do my environment variables are not working ? Maybe there is an additional step I need to make ?

Are you sure these environment variables are being set permanently? Try printing one of the variables in the same script/terminal where you're running terraform init.

Turns out the problem was related to environment variables. I was only setting env variables for the shell process that I had open and then I opened another shell the variables were not there anymore.
I added the variables to the .bashrc file so every time a new shell is launched it automatically adds the environment variables also.
